# Synapse workspace upload package

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-cli

We have set up a pipeline to upload the libraries/packages to synpase workspace using Azure commands

```
az synapse workspace-package upload --workspace-name testsw --package C:/python.whl
```

I tried appending --overwrite just to overwrite the existing library but it threw error.
Do we have any command to overwrite the existing package in Synapse Workspace?

Edit:
Error I got while I appended --overwrite is as below:

Unrecognized arguments : --overwrite

Comment: what is the error you are facing?

Comment: unrecognised argument : --overwrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue with the answer provided by @JayashankarGS
A slight change I have made:

> ```
> $workspaceName = "workspace_name"
> $packageName = "package_name"
> $packageFilePath = "curr_package_name"
>
> $packageExists = az synapse workspace-package show --workspace-name $workspaceName --name $packageName --query "id" -o tsv
>
> if ($packageExists -eq $null) {
> az synapse workspace-package upload --workspace-name $workspaceName --package $packageFilePath
> }
> ```

The reason why I was getting error while deleting the existing whl file was , in Synapse the whl file was being used by some pipeline

Answer (score 1):

There is no option like `--overwrite` in az command, but what you can do is check if package exists.
If exists delete and upload new one.

Below are the commands for that.

```
$workspaceName = "workspace_name"
$packageName = "package_name"
$packageFilePath = "curr_package_name"

$packageExists = az synapse workspace-package show --workspace-name $workspaceName --name $packageName --query "id" -o tsv

if ($packageExists) {
az synapse workspace-package delete --workspace-name $workspaceName --name $packageName --yes
}
az synapse workspace-package upload --workspace-name $workspaceName --package $packageFilePath
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @JayashankarGS, I have tested this out but delete package returned this error : Error: Operation returned an invalid status 'Conflict'